# "No such file or directory" goes away when using tab autocomplete. Comes back when re-doing previous command

Tags: command-line, mount, samba

Example:

```
$ ls -lahF '/mnt/test/test directory 001/'
total 1.0G
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser root    0 Aug 10 01:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser root    0 Aug 10 13:53 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser root 1.0G Aug 10 14:00 testfile.bin*
```

When I try to `ls` this file, it doesn't work:

```
$ ls -lahF '/mnt/test/test directory 001/testfile.bin'
ls: cannot access '/mnt/test/test directory 001/testfile.bin': No such file or directory
```

However, when I don't type the filename myself, but use tab to autocomplete, it does work:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser root 1.0G Aug 10 14:00 '/mnt/test/test directory 001/testfile.bin'*
```

And if I then arrow up, to use previous command, and execute that, it's back to `No such file or directory`.

SEO on searching this just leads me to "autocomplete not working" questions.

Not sure where to even begin looking for this one.

What is going on here? Any help appreciated.

The mount itself is a samba mount. It's the first time I'm seeing this behavior. Could there be anything special about the file? The directory, the full path, maybe the samba connection? How would I check this?

EDIT: As requested:

```
$ echo '/mnt/test/test directory 001/'* | od -c
0000000   /   m   n   t   /   t   e   s   t   /   t   e   s   t       d
0000020   i   r   e   c   t   o   r   y       0   0   1   /   *  \n
0000037
```

And the file itself:

```
$ echo '/mnt/test/test directory 001/testfile.bin'* | od -c
0000000   /   m   n   t   /   t   e   s   t   /   t   e   s   t       d
0000020   i   r   e   c   t   o   r   y       0   0   1   /   t   e   s
0000040   t   f   i   l   e   .   b   i   n  \n
0000052
```

EDIT 2: Doing `strace ls -la` gives slightly different outputs.

When finding the file it gives:

```
lstat("/mnt/test/test directory 001/testfile.bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1027989040, ...}) = 0
```

And not finding it:

```
lstat("/mnt/test/test directory 001/testfile.bin", 0x560a93648988) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

No idea what causes the difference.

Another behavior notice: if doing autocomplete, and then pressing `Home`, moving the cursor the the start of the line, also fails to find the file.

How can moving the cursor have an effect on this?

EDIT 3:

```
/mnt/test/test directory 001/$ ls | od -c
0000000   t   e   s   t   f   i   l   e   .   b   i   n  \n
```

Mount options, credentials and IP editted out:

```
//<EDIT>/remotedir /mnt/test cifs uid=1000,credentials=/home/myuser/.smb_cred_file,vers=2.1 0 0
```

And the output of `mount` shows this, ip and username also editted out:

```
rw,relatime,vers=2.1,cache=strict,username=<EDIT>,domain=,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=<EDIT>,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1
```

The remote machine isn't under my control. To my understanding it is a sort of NAS solution.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a stray utf8 character in the filename (like a newline) that is invisible but causes problems. Try renaming the file, typing the new name by hand

Comment: Please post the output of `echo '/mnt/test/test directory 001/'* | od -c`.

Comment: @terdon Posted as requested.

Comment: That... is weird. The directory is empty. Is this set to be automounted? What's your samba setup? Is it always mounted or mounted on demand? Even then this should work, but just in case, please post the output of first going into the directory with `cd '/mnt/test/test directory 001/'` and then `ls | od -c`. But I suspect it isn't an issue with the name and instead the file is really not there until you `ls` the directory. Presumably because `ls` tries to read the directory while the shell globbing does not.

Comment: It's an always mounted samba connection via `/etc/fstab`. I'll add the result and the mount options to the post.